# Char pointer equal to buffer plus buffer size?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, buffer

Can someone explain this code to me? Or confirm my view on it?

`char *buffer` is allocated to point to `"Hello World\0"`
 And the `buffer_size` is the 12.

So:

`char *var = buffer + buffer_size - 1;`

Now `*var` points to the `'d'` in `"Hello World"`, correct?

Comment: That rather depends on the value of `buffer_size`.

Comment: Good catch - added the size in there.

Comment: Did you try it, before posting the question?

Comment: `buffer` points to 'H', `buffer+1` points to 'e', `buffer+10` points to 'd', and `buffer+11` (which is equal to `var`) points to '\0', and `*var` *is* '\0' (and doesn't point anywhere).

Comment: Going out on a limb, I'm guessing that `buffer_size` is the result of `sizeof("Hello World\0")`, which is 12 even though `strlen("Hello World\0")` is 10. `"Hello World\0"` has two null bytes at the end, one explicit and one because it's a string literal. EDIT: My count is off by one. Makes no sense anymore. Damn.

Comment: Here's a hint: For any `X`, `buffer[X]` is equivalent to `*(buffer + X)`. Would you ask the same question if it was `buffer[buffer_size - 1]`?

Comment: @Wintermute nope, the `\0` isn't counted. It marks the end. it also counts as a single byte.

Comment: @robert `sizeof` is not `strlen`.

Comment: And just to answer a question perhaps implied by the title--Yes, in C it's legal for a pointer to point one element past the end of an array, so long as it is not dereferenced, but only used for comparisons. It is NOT technically legal for it to point to before the beginning of the array, but most compilers allow it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
H e l l o _ W o r l d \0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

As was mentioned in the comments, you should initialize `buffer` like so

```
const char *buffer = "Hello World";
```

Then note that `sizeof(buffer)` is just the sizeof a pointer, not the length of the string. So `buffer_size` should be initialized as

```
size_t buffer_size = strlen( buffer ) + 1;
```

That sets `buffer_size` to 12. So if you want a pointer to the `d`, it's

```
const char *var = buffer + buffer_size - 2;
```

which points `var` to `buffer[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

It points to 'd' if going by string length alone.

`char_pointer + 0` points to the start of the string `'h'`, `+1` points to `'e'` so `+ n` points to the `n + 1`th character. `char_pointer + buffer_size - 1 == 'd'`!

EDIT: Only holds if `buffer_length` is determined from `strlen`, which would give `11`. In the case that it is `12`, which includes the terminating `\0` it will point to the that.

Comment: you missed his `- 1` :-p

Comment: Nope. `buffer[12]` points to one past the buffer, so `buffer[12-1]` points to the terminator see answer from @user3386109.

Comment: Oh right, yeah, he only put in the `buffer_length` after I'd answered. Presumed I was dealing with a string literal.